# Classes in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

There is the following class in CoffeScript:

```
class MyClass

  f: (@x) ->
```

Translating this code in JS we have:

```
(function() {
  var MyClass;

  MyClass = (function() {
    function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.f = function(x) {
      this.x = x;
    };

    return MyClass;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

I don't understand why in order to add function to MyClass I should use prototype for it; why I can't use 'MyClass.f = function(x) ... " ? Please, explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to say `MyClass.f(x)` or `o = new MyClass; o.f(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define

```
class MyClass 
    f: (@x) ->
    @g: (@x) ->
m = new MyClass()
```

you'll find that, `MyClass` has a `g` attribute, but not `f`, while `m` has an `f`, but not `g`.

To access `g` from `m`, you have to use `m.constructor.g`.

Also `MyClass.prototype == m.__proto__`.

To really understand this you need to dig into the prototype inheritance structure of Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

> When the code new foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> - A new object is created, inheriting from foo.prototype.
> - The constructor function foo is called with the specified arguments...
> - The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. ...

So the key point is that the new object inherits (is effectively a copy of) from the class `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the prototype chain, you can assign static methods as well like this:

```
class MyClass

  @f: (@x) ->
```

Which will output:

```
var MyClass;

MyClass = (function() {
  function MyClass() {}

  MyClass.f = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
  };

  return MyClass;

})();
```

Comment: The difference between `C.m()` and `new C().m()` might be a big part of the confusion.